# "ask for assist" or "ask for assistance"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the proper/better wording?

- > ask for assist
- > ask for assistance

I always thought the later (ask for assistance) until seeing someone using "ask for assist" on some SE site, and before editing it I checked it only to find out that "assist" is also a noun. Even more, [here](https://wikidiff.com/assist/assistance) it says:

> assist is a helpful action or an act of giving

So appears to be the correct wording, but still not sure.

Answer (score 3):

First, there are a few issues with grammar that need to be addressed.

*Assist* is a countable noun. That means that you need to use an article in front of it.

> Can you give me **an** assist?
>   I will ask for **an** assist.

So, your first example phrase should really be changed to:

> ask for **an** assist

*Assistance*, on the the other hand, is a mass noun. It *may* take **the** in front of it (although never *an*), but it can also stand on its own. It is based on context:

> I will ask for assistance.
>   Thank you for **the** assistance.

Also, *assist* is both a noun and a verb, so it can be easy to confuse the two.

> Please assist me.

Here, it's a verb, not a noun, and, therefore, you would **not** say, "Please *an* assist me."

So, let's actually look at the two variations of asking for help:

> ask for an assist
>   ask for assistance

Both are grammatical.

(Although, as noted, if you had seen "ask for assist" without *an*, then it was ungrammatical.)

I queried [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) for evidence of which of the two is more common. Annoyingly, or perhaps tellingly, while it charted *ask for assistance* it was unable to find *ask for an assist* at all. (This is made more explicit by [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.ca/) which shows 19,900 hits for the former and only 6 for the latter.)

My own opinion is that *ask for assistance* is the more common of the two. But if you see *ask for an assist*, it would also be acceptable.

---

Note that, per a comment, *ask for an assist* may be more understandable in North America than in the UK.

Comment: Great, thanks. Really weird no results found for "ask for an assist" then.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Google **Books** Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info) won't plot the results when there are too few of them (under 40, I believe). Also, note that https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assist labels *assist* (the noun) in the mentioned meaning as North American. Personally (I'm not a native speaker of English, so my opinion is generally worthless, but still), this use of *assist* looks kinda odd and I'd really only take it to mean the sports thing (described in the linked dictionary), but I'd definitely use the article there.